# Hubot not responding to regex variable

Tags: javascript, regex, coffeescript, hubot

I've been playing around with Hubot for a bit, far too long actually but I'm getting stuck at matching a string in an array. `replies` is an array with some replies.

So this works:

```
module.exports = (robot) ->
    robot.hear /seb/i, (msg) ->
    msg.send msg.random replies
```

However, this does not:

```
regex = new RegExp triggers.join(), 'gi'

module.exports = (robot) ->
    robot.hear regex, (msg) ->
    msg.send msg.random replies
```

`regex` is a string made up of the contents of an array of strings. In this case printing out regex returns `"/seb/i"`.

Anyone care to explain? I never was a big fan of JavaScript and Coffeescript :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `triggers.join('|')`?

Comment: Apparently so. Is that just a rule? Why would it not be able to regex with comma instead? Please @fardjad add that to a proper answer with a possible explaination to my question and I'll mark it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) takes a string parameter as separator. It defaults to `,` when no parameter is given.

Let's assume we have the following array of keywords:

```
const triggers = ["kw1", "kw2", "kw3"]
```

Calling `triggers.join()` will return the string `kw1,kw2,kw3`. Passing that to **RegExp** constructor will create a **RegExp** object [that matches the exact string `kw1,kw2,kw3` (also ignores case because of the `i` flag)](https://www.debuggex.com/r/rfB0QSXztJ4IG17t).

In order to match multiple keywords with a regex, you must separate them with [special-or (`|`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-or).

So instead of

```
regex = new RegExp triggers.join(), 'gi'
```

You should write

```
regex = new RegExp triggers.join('|'), 'i'
```

You might also want to drop the `g` (global search) flag as well, since it's enough to match the first occurrence of a keyword in your case.